# How to display date (day and month) on each item in RecyclerView android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-calendar

I have a `fragment` that has a `RecyclerView` of six items (meaning every day of the week from Monday to Saturday). Is there any way to display the current date (day and month) on all these elements, so that the countdown starts from Monday of the current week?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using LocalDate.

```
val thisWeekMonday = LocalDate.now()
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
val daysOfThisWeek = List(7) { thisWeekMonday + Period.ofDays(it) }
```

You can use DateTimeFormatter to convert it to a human-readable String for use in your List that you put in the RecyclerView. For example:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d")
val formattedDaysOfThisWeek = daysOfThisWeek.map { it.format(formatter) }
```